# Where can I find a list of all Xulrunner preferences available?

Tags: xul, xulrunner

I'm looking for a list of all preferences that I can set on prefs.js, looks like there's no such thing in the mozilla's page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can set any preference.

If you are wanting to see a list of all preferences, you can open the Preferences window - [just open the chrome in a window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner_tips#Useful_Chrome_URLs) : chrome://global/content/config.xul

If you're asking for a single place where every existing preference from a vanilla xulrunner install i documented, I don't think that exists.

Comment: You mean "chrome://global/content/config.xul" (no http). Looks like there's only Firefox preferences there. Sadly I either think there's no documentation on that.